# Making Flexible Height Containers for Responsive Design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my site responsive and I'm having trouble creating containers divs where their height responds to the content within them. I've tried setting height to 100% but it's not working for.

Most of the content blocks are flowing below each other as I resize my browser but the containers aren't expanding to fit around them.

[HomePage](http://www.tassolarpanels.com.au/)

Does anyone know do I have anything fundamentaly wrong in how the page is built that is preventing me from acheiving this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your floats. One example is `.mission-statement`. When you have multiple divs floating inside a div, the container collapses on itself. In your case, it's only partially collapsing because you have a min-height set.

You do this easily by doing something like this:

```
.mission-statement:after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
```

To affect all divs you can change `.mission-statement:after` to `div:after`

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly! Been trying to fix this for ages and was thinking I needed to restructure the page to fix it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Images will automatically have a height of 100% of the image relative to the width and the percent tag is percent of the browser window. What you may want is a width tag that might be max-width=*px and let the height be determined by the image itself.

Comment: Ok this will sort out the issue I'm having with the images thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting me write you an answer I will refer to a really good thread about this. The solution anyway is something called clearfix.

[css - What is clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554054/3007816)